# How to split a multibyte string into words in Php?

Tags: php, regex

How to split a multibyte string into words in Php? 
Here is what I have done so far, but I would like to improve the code...

```
   mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8');
   mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8');
   $arr = mb_split( '[\s\[\]().,;:-_]', $str );
```

Is there a way to say that a *word* is a sequence of "alpha"-characters (not using the notation a-z, since I would like to include non-latin characters)

Comment: What is your string like, and what charset are you using.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this baby here:

```
preg_match_all('/[\p{L}\p{M}]+/u', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```

**Matches all possible letter with their accents as words:**

```
     "
[\p{L}\p{M}]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                   # A character with the Unicode property “letter” (any kind of letter from any language)
                   # A character with the Unicode property “mark” (a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.))
   +               # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"
```

**[See it.](http://ideone.com/vAZIW)**

Comment: It miss the last letter in the words if it is non-latin. The sentence "också här finns hö" => ocks, här, finns, h

Comment: @ragnarius Fixed. Reason was that word boundary doesn't play well with UTF-8 :)

Comment: Great! But what does /u mean?

Comment: @ragnarius Be sure to check latest edit. /u means support large Unicode ranges (ie: [\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}] or \x{10FFFFF}).

Comment: Hm. It does not find the words "också" and "hö" in the sentence "också! här finns hö!"

Comment: @ragnarius Well of course it doesn't since it expects a space or the end of start of the string. So you just want sequences of any letter from any language. Latest update - hopefully :)

Comment: It does not find words ending with a non white character (such as !,? etc)

Comment: @ragnarius Did you click on the link?

Comment: I am not sure what link you mean? Your answer has rolled back for some reason but I think the present answer works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Many languages do not use words (Chinese). Should the function return the whole string in that case? In PHP, explode() is binary safe, so it might be faster to just use that if you only need a single separator.

Comment: No I need many separators, every character that is not a letter should be a separator. Not handling chinese would be okay in version 1.0

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use `\w` for it?

Comment: Is this an answer? A guess? A hint? A question?